# Is the engi surrender event a penalty for honesty?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I've run into this event a few times. There's an engi ship that automatically surrenders without a fight, saying something like "transfer of goods acceptable?"  There are two choices, 1) to accept the surrendered goods, 2) to assure them that you mean no harm.

Every time this happens, I can't bring myself to take their stuff, so I choose the second option and they take off without another word.

Is there anything more to this event, or is the optimal choice always to accept their stuff?

Comment: I don't have any statistics, but I have had them been surprised by my graciousness to let them leave, and they paid me anyway. I'm guessing it's 50/50 that they'll pay either zero or +50% over their original offer.

Comment: Ok.  I figured there had to be at least a chance of good things happening, but was surprised when they never happened to me.  I was actually originally hoping for a silent diplomatic affect to engi events for the rest of the game/sector.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's always better to accept the surrendered goods.

If you accept the surrendered goods, you get a standard reward of random level.

If you don't accept the goods, there's a 50% chance you get a standard reward of random level (i.e. the same thing), and a 50% chance they just leave.

Comment: Can you cite a source for this information? It seems weird to me that they'd give you a choice where there was a clear, and 100% true, better choice. That's not really much of a choice.

Comment: @aslum: The game data; the event is named `ENGI_SURRENDER`.

Comment: But those poor engis!